# Cakephp/SQL how to define a hasandbelongstomany relationship with quantities?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, schema

My problem is as follows. I have the following models: `Recipe and Ingredient`. I want to define the two in a `HasAndBelongsToMany` relationship, but the complication comes from the following: I want recipes to be able to possess a quantity of each ingredient.

Quantity will be defined by two fields: Amount and Unit. So on an abstract level here's an example of what I want to see/be able to query:

```
Apple Pie: 
   Ingredients:
      1 pound of apples
      2 tablespoons of sugar

Orange Juice:
   Ingredients:
      1 cup of water
      0.5 tablespoons of sugar
      5 gobbles of googber
```

And I also wish to be able to query an ingredient and have it return which recipes are tied to it:

Recipes that contain sugar: Apple Pie and Orange Juice
Recipes that contain googber: Orange Juice

I know this is strictly speaking a sql schema question, but since I am implementing the website in cakephp, I would prefer if the answers references the Model/Controller/View paradigm that cakephp uses as well as the builtin cakephp methods.

(Just so it would be easier for me to convert your solutions to my code. I do not like digging in the cakephp documentation, their search function is very buggy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model

If you are not, you should be using [debug()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1128/debug) at all times when trying to resolve your data arrays. You can use debug in your views, controllers, models etc. It is VERY useful.

Without seeing your data array structure, I would first say try to access the User model from a find like:

$this->Model_1->Model_2->Model_3->find('all'); or you can set your recursion level to 2 and see how much data you get back and all relations in an array. But use debug() to find out if you need to modify your model relations etc..

Comment: Awesome, but when I do a find, it won't automatically join a tertiary table. IngredientQuantity belongsTo Recipe and Ingredient, and Recipe belongsTo User. So when I query for IngredientQuantity I can now get information about both Recipe and Ingredient, but it won't let me also ask for fields from User. What do I do other than make a manual JOIN?